# Why my iPhone does not enter DFU?

Tags: iphone, itunes

After trying several tutorials online, I do not understand why my iPhone does not enter DFU. I checked multiple tutorials so the source should be correct.

I also followed exactly. I repeat, EXACTLY the steps of this video: https://youtu.be/U8ltCY8e5RY?t=219 to enter DFU which seem pretty obvious and people in the comments of the video claim that they succeeded entering DFU.

For me it does not work. I really tried MANY times. It always goes from the black screen to the apple and restarts normally. Obviously nothing shows up in iTunes since the device does not enter DFU.

Question: What am I missing? Is my iPhone like an alien or there is a ghost inside, or why everyone claims this work and for me is not working?

iPhone Xs
iOS 13.3.1
MBP 2018, Catalina, iTunes Version 12.9.5.5

Comment: Can you actually tell us the steps you followed, so we don't have to go watch 6 minutes of YouTube video to check what you are doing.

Comment: I modified the link with the instant when the enter DFU part starts. It is less than 30 seconds.

Comment: It still a) requires people to go offsite to see what you did & b) if the link ever disappears so does the entire point of this question.

Comment: I want to avoid to repeat the same because I might repeat it wrongly. Since is documented in so many places, I think is error prone to rewrite it here. I think the most vivid and clear way to reproduce the steps is in a video.

I could enumerate the steps by texting but that's AGES far from seeing it in real in a video.

If you feel uncomfortable watching the video, is fine you do not need to answer this question if you do not feel up to it. But for me this way of formulating it is the most clear.

Comment: It's not whether I feel uncomfortable watching the video. but that this question has no basis at all without the **actual steps you took**. We weren't watching you watching the video. We don't know whether you followed it accurately or not. We don't know what you did until you tell us.

Comment: Well, in that case what you need is not a text-based enumeration of the steps (which you can find all over online) but you would need a video of me taking the steps. What I believe is really useful and I will attach it to my question. However, it does not help you at all since you do not wanna watch a video anyway.
So again, I am really glad you try to help but I understand you might not want to invest the effort to watch the video (either mine or from someone else), so is fine if you do not answer this question.

Comment: @Tururu Maybe you have a fake iPhone? That's what happened to me.

Answer (score 1):

The steps in the video are correct. The steps are the same for any iPhone Xs.

You need to follow the steps in the video accurately. I.e. ensure you're pressing and holding the right buttons at the right times, ensuring to keep holding the volume down button when you release the side button - and releasing the side button only after counting as indicated.

The steps are:

1. Open iTunes
2. Connect the iPhone with your Mac using a USB cable
3. Press the "Volume Up" button and release it
4. Press the "Volume Down" button and release it
5. Press and hold the "Power" button until the screne turns black
6. While still holding the "Power" button, also press and hold the "Volume Down" button
7. Count 5 seconds
8. Release the "Power" button, but keep holding the "Volume Down" button
9. Count 10 seconds

Now iTunes should let you know that the iPhone is in DFU mode.

If you did all those things correctly and it still goes from the black screen to ordinary startup, you must have a hardware error (i.e. button problem or similar). In that case, take the phone back to the seller.

Comment: Yes I completed those steps. Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place? - Have you tested that the buttons actually are working?

Comment: This answer should be a comment. We don't have the full picture yet of what the OP did.

Comment: The steps aren’t in question, it whether the OP followed said instructions correctly.  Given his adamant resistance to following the requests of some of the most knowledgeable folks here on AD, I’m increasingly convinced he didn’t follow the instructions properly.

Comment: Ofcourse, everyone knows that he didn't follow the instructions properly. That's why I wrote the steps down, so that perhaps he has a second chance of trying to get it right. If the buttons works ordinarily, and he can't get into DFU mode - he's just not doing it right.

Comment: You are right guys, I will upload a video. The buttons seem to work correctly, i.e. the hardware. I can turn on/turn down the volume. I also can lock/unlock the screen.